# Checkbox component presents different behavior for different users

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a Windows Form application with a checkbox that presents different behaviour according to the user. The component appears in the form only for the user who installed first the application.

For other users that have the same privileges, in the same machine, the checkbox is not visible. I already tried to uninstall and reinstall the application with different users, but the problem persists.

In my code, there´s nothing that changes the `Visible` property to true or false, I just let the default value to `true`

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Is it created at run-time? Do you change it's position? Is it inside a container which auto-sizes or otherwise changes its ClientArea? Do you change the z-order of other controls? Do you add, move or otherwise change the Location or Size of other Controls, maybe just because some are anchored/docked? [... more ...]

Answer (score 0):

Try resize the window that contains the checkbox. You are probably setting the size or the location of the checkbox in a wrong way. Try to use proper anchor property and see if the problem resolves.

Comment: Hi Saeed, thanks for your comments. The problem was a too high Windows display resolution, defined by user. Cheers